# \sqrt breaks \diagmat?

Tags: math-mode, typography, physics

When using the `diagmat` module of the `physics2` package, a \sqrt{} as any of the entries gives me the error: `Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line x.`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, physics2}
\usephysicsmodule{diagmat}

\begin{document}
\[
    \diagmat{ 1, 2, \sqrt[3]{4} }
\]
\end{document}
```

Edit: File List as requested:

```
*File List*
 article.cls    2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 amsmath.sty    2023/05/13 v2.17o AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
physics2.sty    2023/04/02 v0.2.1 Tools for typesetting math for physics.
  keyval.sty    2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
phy-common.sty    2023/03/29 `common' module of `physics2.sty'
phy-diagmat.sty    2023/01/25 `diagmat' module of `physics2.sty'
phy-explsetup.sty    2023/01/25 `explsetup' module of `physics2.sty'
l3backend-pdftex.def    2023-04-19 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
```

Comment: 'Works for me': please add `\listfiles` to your input, and run the example with the `\sqrt` removed so you can get the `File list` from your `.log` to edit into the question.

Comment: You are using v0.2.1 of `physics2`: it's now at 'release' status, v1.0.1 - 'update your TeX system' seems like the solution